# GPG Unable to fetch URI | Permission Denied

Tags: docker, gnupg, permission-denied, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to build a docker container to use with NVIDIA/CUDA, and I've been having issue with fetching these two keys when building my image. In my Dockerfile, I have:

```
RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/3bf863cc.pub
```

However, I get an error from GPG saying there are permission issues when accessing these keys (see screenshot below).

```
gpg: requesting key from 'https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub'
gpg: WARNING: unable to fetch URI https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub: Permission denied
```

A few things I've tried:

1. Rebuilding the image
2. Made sure my user is added in the docker group
3. Deleted cuda.list and nvidia-ml.list from the container after running the above commands
4. Tried the new NVIDIA cuda keyring system instead of manually downloading the two keys

My environment:
Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
docker-ce 20.10.17
docker container (where error is occurring): Ubuntu 18.04

I am wondering if this has anything to do with permission issues specifically with docker or any changes in 22.04 pop os/Ubuntu. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

[gpg error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWX0X.png)

Answer (score 1):

On a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 system, I also get an error when first trying to import that key using `apt-key`:

```
root@9cb48ec99a4b:/# apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.5rdyBHsBVw/gpg.1.sh --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
gpg: requesting key from 'https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub'
gpg: WARNING: unable to fetch URI https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub: General error
```

However, if I first import the key manually with gpg:

```
root@9cb48ec99a4b:/# curl -sf https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub | gpg --import
gpg: key F60F4B3D7FA2AF80: public key "cudatools <cudatools@nvidia.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

Afterwards `apt-key` seems to work:

```
root@9cb48ec99a4b:/# apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.k2G5gnmspg/gpg.1.sh --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
gpg: requesting key from 'https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub'
gpg: key F60F4B3D7FA2AF80: public key "cudatools <cudatools@nvidia.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

Comment: That's a great suggestion! I gave it a go but unfortunately I'm still running into the same issue :( 

it seems like you get a general error, but mine still returns permission error: 

gpg: requesting key from 'https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub'
gpg: WARNING: unable to fetch URI https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub: Permission denied

Apologies that I didn't format this properly. Still new to this site. Thanks!